# Geometric interpretation of monotone operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, intuition, monotone-operator-theory

Recall that a monotone operator is defined by the relationship as follows:
$$\langle y - x, F(y) - F(x)\rangle \geq 0, \quad \forall x,y \in X$$ 
($X$ is a Hilbert space)

1. What is a good geometric interpretation of this relationship? Obviously we could say that $y - x$ and $F(y) - F(x)$ maintains a less than $90$ deg angle, but can we say more about that?
2. Does $\langle y - x, F(y) - F(x)\rangle \leq 0$ also define a monotone operator? Notice we cannot just pull out negative signs in the original inequality and reverse the sign this way.

Comment: I assume that a'b means the inner product of a and b,which is usually written (a,b).

Comment: What you've defined doesn't make sense for set-valued operators (e.g $F(x)$ could be a set, since $F$ is  a set-valued operator in general...).

Comment: What you have at no. 2 is called an accretive operator in a Hilbert space.

Comment: @NormalHuman You're right of course. That's what I actually meant. However the ironic first sentence in your message applies probably to your friends and you could have skipped it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part 2  is easier to answer: no, the way monotone operators are defined in functional analysis, $-F$ is not in general  monotone when $F$ is. (This is unlike the concept of monotonicity in real analysis). Monotone operators correspond to (non-strictly) increasing functions. The reverse inequality defines [dissipative operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator).

Part 1, geometric interpretation beyond "at most 90 degree rotation". If the graph of an increasing function is rotated by $45$ degrees clockwise, the  result is the graph of a $1$-Lipschitz function. (And conversely.) This property also holds for monotone operators, in the following form: consider the graph of $F$ as a subset of $X\times X$ and apply the linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,y-x)$ in $X\times X$. The image of the graph of $F$ under this transformation is the graph of a $1$-Lipschitz function. Indeed,the inequality
$$
\|(y_1-x_1)-(y_2 -x_2)\| \le \|(y_1 +x_1)-(y_2 +x_2)\|
$$
is equivalent to $\langle y_1-y_2,x_1-x_2\rangle \ge 0$.